# Cocoa - how to get currently selected object in collection view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a `NSCollectionView` in a cocoa application.

I can get information about the currently selected object in the collection view through the following roundabout way:

```
NSIndexSet* index = [self.currentCollectionView selectionIndexes];
CardModel* card = [[self.currentCollectionView itemAtIndex:index.firstIndex] representedObject];
```

Does the `NSCollectionView` class have a method that returns the selected object? Or is this the preferred way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `NSTableView` you do not have delegates/notifications which gives notifies you about the selection. So `selectionIndexes` is the way to go.

I am not sure if you have set up observers for array controllers or not. But the code which you have shown is only to retrieve the selected objects. To get notified about the selection of objects you need to add observer for key path `selectionIndexes` (or what ever is set in IB) on array controllers.

```
[myArrayController addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes" 
       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
       context:nil];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualTo:@"selectionIndexes"])
    {
        // This will be invoked whenever objects are selected in Collection View.
        // Now collectionView selectionIndexes can be used to get the selected objects.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if `selectionIndexes` is the only way to access an `NSCollectionView`'s selection the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use bindings in the xib. Set up an NSArrayController for the items to be represented by the views in the collection. In the xib, in the Bindings Inspector of the Collection View, bind the Content of the CollectionView to the `collectionViewArrayController.arrangedObjects`. Also bind the Selection Indexes to `collectionViewArrayController.selectionIndexes`. Now you can make an outlet to the array controller, say in the App Delegate, and access the selected objects there.

For example, declare a `selectedCard` property, also a `collectionViewAC` outlet property connected to the`collectionViewArrayController`. Now you can get the card item(s) you wish by way of `selectedObjects`.

```
- (id)selectedCard
{
    id selectedCards = [collectionViewAC selectedObjects];
    if ([selectedCards count]) {
        return [selectedCards objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Use of bindings keeps everything observed and updated.